# How to split a data.frame into an array by a factor?

Tags: arrays, r, split

If we want to split a `data.frame` by a "factor" `f` we usually do:

```
split(df1, df1$f)
```

But how do we do that when we want to split the `data.frame` into an `array`? I find my code a little awkward because of the two `t`, also the `max` could be a bit unreliable:

```
A <- array(t(as.matrix(df1)), dim=c(ncol(df1), max(df1$id), max(df1$f)))
apply(A, c(1, 3), t)
```

Is there a less complicated base R solution?

The following won't give me what I want, since `str` still yields `list`s.

```
as.array(split(df1, df1$f))
as.array(lapply(split(df1, df1$f), as.matrix))
as.array(lapply(split(df1, df1$f), function(x) matrix(unlist(x), nrow(x))))
```

***Data***

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), f = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), x1 = c(14L, 15L, 4L, 10L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 
2L, 5L, 9L, 3L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 11L), x2 = c(12L, 15L, 6L, 9L, 
1L, 14L, 11L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 8L, 5L, 10L, 13L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mylist = split(df1, df1$f)
dims = dim(mylist[[1]])
array(sapply(mylist, function(x){
    m = as.matrix(x)
    array(m, dim = dims)
}), dim = c(dims, length(mylist)))
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that's a reliable solution. But still a lot of effort, right?